# Prolog transpose of a Matrix using decompose

Tags: matrix, prolog, logic

First of all, I know there are other codes to make the transpose of a matrix in other questions, but my problem is specific one:

In a homework I was asked to build a `decompose/3` code which separates the first element of each list from the rest of the elements.

After this I was asked to create a code to `transpose/3` a matrix. *(If the input is not a matrix, it can fail, the purpose is not to check whether it is a matrix or not).*

I have the following codes `decompose/3`, `transpose/3`, and `transpose1/3` so far: (transpose and transpose1 are the same but with a different base case)

```
%4. transpose(M, R)
%Input transpose([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], R).

decompose([], [], []).
decompose([[H|T]|T0], [H|L1], [T|L2]) :- 
    decompose(T0, L1, L2).

transpose(M,[L1|Z]):-                       #This code works for 3 rows
    decompose(M,L1,L2),
    transpose(L2,Z).

transpose1([[X],[Y],[Z],[B]],[[X,Y,Z,B]]).  #This code works for up to 4 rows
transpose1([H|T],[L1|R]):-    
    decompose([H|T],L1,L2),
    transpose1(L2,R).
```

So the input matrix is a [3 x 2] in this example, and it works fine, for both, but if my matrix has more than 4 rows, `transpose` does not work anymore, and because of the base case `transpose1([[X],[Y],[Z],[B]],[[X,Y,Z,B]]).` it can manipulate up to 4 rows, but if the matrix is bigger, then the outcome is `false`.

Any idea how to manipulate my code? How to make the base case apply for any number of rows on my matrix? Why is this not working?

Thank you!

Comment: Why isn't your base case just `transpose1([], []).` instead of `transpose1([[X],[Y],[Z],[B]],[[X,Y,Z,B]]).`? Your recursion is done when you're out of elements, not when you're on the last one. Plus, as written, a single element in each row would match both of your predicate clauses as they are currently expressed.

Comment: When doing that, it just doesn't run anymore. So how I had the code, if I input: `transpose1([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[5,6]], R).` It stops here according to the trace. `Fail: (10) decompose([[], [], [], []], _G1273, _G1288) ? creep`. If I use what you told me, it generates the same error, but it also fail with 3 rows. I do not understand.

Comment: It obviously has other issues, but the base case does need to use empty lists, not lists of one element. That's what limits you to 4 rows. It's incorrect to do it that way. Did you test your `decompose`? Does it work correctly?

Comment: Decompose returns: `L1 = [1, 3, 5],
L2 = [[2, 8], [4], [6]].` With input: `decompose([[1,2,8],[3,4],[5,6]], L1, L2).` Which is fine, I also have another code for decompose which apparently was less efficient so I am not using it. But still I guess transpose is having some issues with L2, since it is a list of lists. This was the reason for trying. `transpose1([[X],[Y],[Z],[B]],[[X,Y,Z,B]])` I was thinking `decompose` was taking care of empty lists.

Comment: `decompose` needs to handle empty lists, too. As does `transpose`.

Comment: `decompose`, when it gets to the end, comes back with `[[], [], ..., []]` when it does the last element (e.g., `decompose([[a], [b]], X, Y).` results in `A = [a,b]` and `Y = [[], []]`, not `Y = []`). If you modify it to come back with just `[]` then `transpose([], [])` will work as a base case.

Comment: Interesting, hopefully I get some luck with that. Thank you.

Comment: Play with it a bit and see what you come up with! You should be able to avoid having a literal fixed number of elements and use your `transpose` (not your `transpose1`).